# Where should I put the variable scanner declaration? "int figureNumber = stdin.nextInt();"

Tags: java, try-catch

I want to make it so that a user entering the wrong data type as figureNumber will see a message from me saying "Please enter an integer" instead of the normal error message, and will be given another chance to enter an integer. I started out trying to use try and catch, but I couldn't get it to work.

Sorry if this is a dumb question. It's my second week of an intro to java class.

```
import java. util.*;

public class Grades {

public static void main(String args []) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(" Please enter an integer: ");
    int grade = stdin.nextInt();
    method2 ();
    if (grade % 2 == 0) { 
        grade -= 1; 
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <=(grade/2); i++) { 
            method1 ();
            method3 ();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well then, don't put it in the try block. Also, `figureNu8mber.nextInt()` won't even compile.

Comment: `int figureNumber; try { figureNumber = stdin.nextInt(); ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(" Welcome! Please enter the number of figures for your totem pole: ");

        while (!stdin.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("That's not a number! Please enter a number: ");
            stdin.next();
        }

        int figureNumber = stdin.nextInt();
        eagle();
        if (figureNumber % 2 == 0) { //determines if input number of figures is even
            figureNumber -= 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= (figureNumber / 2); i++) {
            whale();
            human();
        }
    }
```

You need to check the input. The hasNextInt() method is true if the input is an integer. So this while loop asks the user to enter a number until the input is a number. Calling next() method is important because it will remove the previous wrong input from the Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    int figureNumber = stdin.nextInt();
    eagle();
    if (figureNumber % 2 == 0) { //determines if input number of figures is even
        figureNumber -= 1; 
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <=(figureNumber/2); i++) { 
        whale();
        human();
    }
}
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print("Input must be an integer");
}
```

You probably want to do something like this. Don't forget to add `import java.util.*;` at the beginning of .java file.

Answer (score 0):

You want something in the form:

1. Ask for input
2. If input incorrect, say so and go to step 1.

A good choice is:

```
Integer num = null; // define scope outside the loop
System.out.println("Please enter a number:"); // opening output, done once 
do {
    String str = scanner.nextLine(); // read anything
    if (str.matches("[0-9]+")) // if it's all digits
        num = Integer.parseInt(str);
    else
        System.out.println("That is not a number. Please try again:"); 
} while (num == null);
// if you get to here, num is a number for sure
```

A `do while` is a good choice because you always at least one iteration.

It's important to read the whole line as a String. If you try to read an `int` and one isn't there the call will explode.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually test the value before you assign it. You don't need to do any matching.

```
...
int figureNumber = -1;
while (figureNumber < 0) {
    System.out.print(" Welcome! Please enter the number of figures for your totem pole: ");
    if (stdin.hasNextInt()){
        figureNumber = stdin.nextInt(); //will loop again if <0
    } else {
        std.next(); //discard the token
        System.out.println("Hey! That wasn't an integer! Try again!");
    }
}
...
```

Comment: A little slow on the typing :) Same idea, but Zsolt's answer is a bit more succint, though mine will make sure you get a positive integer.